# asp.net mvc window open with custom properties and model

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model

I have a form with submit, which opens a pdf file

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "custom" }))
  {
   ......
   @Html.TextboxFor(m=>m.Name)
   <input type="submit" value="Open File"/>
  }
```

I want this to open the file in a new window.
- I need to pass the model to the post method (solution1)
- I can open the new window but i also need to name it and re-open a file in the same window. (solution2)

I have the 2 possible solutions but I want to combine their features.

`solution1:`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "custom" }))
  {
   ......
   @Html.TextboxFor(m=>m.Name)
   <input type="submit" value="Open File" formtarget="_blank"/>
  }
```

`solution2:`

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "custom" }))
  {
    ......
    @Html.TextboxFor(m=>m.Name)
    <a href="#" onclick="fileDownload()" >Download File</a>
  }

<script type="text/javascript">
    function fileDownload() {

        var title = "my file";

        var win = window.open("@Url.Action("DisplayFile", "MyFile")?name=@Model.Name", title);
        win.onload = function () { this.document.title = title; };
    };
</script>
```

In `Solution2` i don't want to pass model as url parameters, i want it to be a `POST` call.
In `Solution1` i can't seem to customize the `title` of the new window.

Either of the solutions are fine by me, so if someone can figureout one of them or a combination i'll just use that.

EDIT: updated with sample model value

Comment: In version 2 are you referring to passing title as a url parameter?

Comment: ive added a sample model value- `Name`, (syntax maybe off) i want to send that using `POST`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you could do this. Firstly, you could use the code from your solution 1 but add a parameter to your controller to accept the title of the new page. The value can be set via a hidden field on the form (which you can manipulate via javascript). You can then set a property on the `ViewBag` and output that in the title:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
```

Form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "custom" }))
{   
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Name)
    @Html.Hidden("Title", "My File")
    <input type="submit" value="Open File" formtarget="_blank" />
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SomeClass model, string title)
{
    ViewBag.Title = title;

    //do something profound..

    return View(model);
}
```

Alternatively, you could intercept the `submit` and perform the post yourself via javascript then write the result manually to a new window. I've used jQuery below for ease as an example but this would be possible in pure javascript if you can't / don't want to use jQuery. I've given the form an id so I can access the submit event:

Form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "custom", id="myForm" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    <input type="submit" value="Open File" />
}
```

Script:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            var win = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");
            var title = "my file";

            win.onload = function () {
                this.document.write(response);
                this.document.title = title;
            };
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: This has several issues, most notable of which is that you cannot write PDFs like this and trigger native browser functionality of displaying/downloading the PDF.

Comment: @Mrchief, interesting, i liked the ajax solution of `petelids`(s/o says can't notify 2 users) but i didn't think about the issues you mentioned. I'll test it out a little more and get back

Answer (score 1):

Writing a PDF file to browser is tricky, especially cross browser. You need to ensure that it has the correct Content headers, especially `content-type` which needs to be `application/pdf`. You cannot set this via JavaScript so server-side rendering is your best option. Do note that there are few client side options but they don't work well across all browsers.

Secondly, your 1st solution is fine because various browsers handle window title differently while displaying PDF files. Modern browsers read the PDF [document's metadata](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF18.html) and display `Title` property, if it has one. If not, they just display the filename. Older browser may display the filename if it has one or the temp file path or something else if nothing else is available.

Since you're not loading an HTML document, `document.title` has no meaning in this case. This is default browser behavior and you can't control it, least of it in a way that works consistently across browsers.

If PDF titles are not in your control, you can control the filename that gets shown (assuming the PDF doesn't have a title or for whatever reason, browser doesn't display it) by setting

`Content-Disposition: inline; filename=<your title.pdf>`

This header needs to be specified before specifying `Content-Type` and can only contain ASCII characters.

**Another alternative** (to show a custom title) is to show the PDF in a iFrame in the target page. 
You can remove borders of the iframe, remove padding/margin of `body` element and adjust the height/width of iframe to match that of the window to make it look like you're only showing the PDF. See this [demo](http://jsbin.com/hokapezigusu/1/) and corresponding [source](http://jsbin.com/hokapezigusu/1/edit?html,css,output) (to show the PDF in a iFrame that makes it look like its loaded in the main window).

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Look ma - custom PDF title!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id=wrapper>
    <iframe src="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/latin9.pdf">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

div#wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div#wrapper > iframe {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```